# Move comp to comp Cobol but don't work

Tags: cobol

I try doing the following:

I have three variables in a file ETTMAS18:

```
C43LECA  PIC S9(09) COMP. 
C43LCOME PIC S9(09) COMP. 
C43CCHEC PIC  X(01).
```

These variables contained:

```
C43LECA    = 000000999  (three last positions)
C43LCOME   = 000000888  (five last positions)
C43CCHEC   = 1
```

And I changed to one variable: 999008881

Then move to `W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME        PIC S9(9) USAGE COMP.`

```
COPY ETTMAS18: 

    10  C43LECA               PIC S9(09) COMP. 
    10  C43LCOME              PIC S9(09) COMP. 
    10  C43CCHEC              PIC  X(01). 



    05 WS-COMERC-AUX.                                             
       10 C43LECA    PIC 9(3).                                   
       10 C43LCOME   PIC 9(5).                                   
       10 C43CCHEC   PIC 9(1).                                   

    05 WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN REDEFINES WS-COMERC-AUX PIC S9(9) USAGE COMP. 

    10 W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME        PIC S9(9) USAGE COMP.

     MOVE 0                      TO WS-COMERC-AUX                 
                                    WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN             

     MOVE C43LECA  IN ETTMAS18 TO C43LECA    IN WS-COMERC-AUX   
     MOVE C43LCOME IN ETTMAS18 TO C43LCOME   IN WS-COMERC-AUX   
     MOVE C43CCHEC IN ETTMAS18 TO C43CCHEC   IN WS-COMERC-AUX   

     MOVE WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN       TO W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME         
                                     W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME-DES     

     IF WS-FECHA-ACT = '2015-03-10'                               
         DISPLAY 'C43LECA  IN ETTMAS18: ' C43LECA  IN ETTMAS18     
         DISPLAY 'C43LCOME IN ETTMAS18: ' C43LCOME IN ETTMAS18     
         DISPLAY 'C43CCHEC IN ETTMAS18: ' C43CCHEC IN ETTMAS18     
         DISPLAY 'C43LECA IN WS-COMERC-AUX : ' 
                                          C43LECA    IN WS-COMERC-AUX 
         DISPLAY 'C43LCOME IN WS-COMERC-AUX : '                     
                                          C43LCOME   IN WS-COMERC-AUX 
         DISPLAY 'C43CCHEC IN WS-COMERC-AUX : '                     
                                          C43CCHEC   IN WS-COMERC-AUX 
         DISPLAY 'WS-COMERC-AUX: '      WS-COMERC-AUX               
         DISPLAY 'WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN: ' WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN           
         DISPLAY 'W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME: '                         
                                       W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME           
         DISPLAY '******************************************'       
     END-IF
```

Displays:

```
   C43LECA  IN ETTMAS18: 000000999   
   C43LCOME IN ETTMAS18: 000000888   
   C43CCHEC IN ETTMAS18: 1           
   C43LECA IN WS-COMERC-AUX : 999     
   C43LCOME IN WS-COMERC-AUX : 00888 
   C43CCHEC IN WS-COMERC-AUX : 1     
   WS-COMERC-AUX: 999008881     This value is the correct value.     
   WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN: 10105806M     (I don't understand) 
   W-CTOAZ710-COA43LCOME: 10105806M (I don't understand)
```

In the output (w-ctoaz710-coa43lcome) is truncated:

```
       9990
```

With hexadecimal values:

```
       9990 
       FFFF 
       9990
```

Could someone explain?

Comment: I think your "WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN REDEFINES WS-COMERC-AUX" should be defined as 9(9), not 9(9) COMP.  You're redefining the first 4 bytes of WS-COMERC-AUX with a binary zero (low value).

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, this solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
05 WS-COMERC-AUX-BIN REDEFINES WS-COMERC-AUX PIC S9(9) USAGE COMP.
```

All that does is allow your program to use a new data-definition. There is no change to the data (unless you make one).

This means you have "character" data, and then you are just saying "hey, I'm going to use this as binary".

The easiest thing for you to do is to remove the COMP from your REDEFINES. A `USAGE DISPLAY`numeric field will then be MOVEd to the binary field, and the compiler will generate the code necessary for translation.

The reason you get the truncation on your file is because you have an 8-byte character value treated as a four-byte binary value. If you "look" at the four-byte binary value, it will appear to be a truncated "character" value.

Comment: Thanks for your explain Bill.